# HP DX5150, MS-7050 v. 1.3 Motherboard front panel pin connectors

Tags: motherboard, led, wiring

I recently purchased and installed a MS-7050 v. 1.3 motherboard into a regular non-HP case and thus the front panel connectors are different than the original OEM connectors which are all bundled together. The HP support website does not have this information available and someone from HP indicated in response to a support forum question that this information is not available.

What is the motherboard pin schematic for the front panel i/o connectors (power, reset, hdd led, and power led)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boy this was hard to find. I hope it is what you are looking for.

F_P1 PinOut

```
17 15 13 11 9 7 5 3 1
18 16 null 12 10 8 6 4 2
```

SHORT:

```
HDD led op 1/3
Power led op 2/4
Power Sw op 6/8
Reset Sw op 5/7
```

LONG:

Pin Signal name Motherboard signal Implementation

```
1 HDLEDPWR HDLEDPWR Pulled up to Vcc through 330ohm resistor
2 BLINK-GRN GONE-2_SLEEP* and MESSAGE_WAITING* Routed to both GPIO ports and PIIX4
3 HDACT* HDACT* Routed from pin 39 of primary and secondary IDE ports. Signal pulled high.
4 BLINK-YEL GONE-2_SLEEP* and MESSAGE_WAITING* Routed to both GPIO ports and PIIX4
5 Ground Ground Routed to ground
6 SWITCH_ON SW_ON Routed to PWRBT* signal on PIIX4 and pulled up to SB3V
7 FP_RESET* FP_RESET* Connected to motherboard PWRGD_ITP signal power good) and pulled up to Vcc3 
8 Ground Ground Routed to ground
9 Vcc Vcc Routed to Vcc
10 FPSLP COMATOSE* Routed to SMBALERT/GPI11 on PIIX4
11 IRRX IRRX Routed to IRRX pin on SIO
12 FPSLP_PWR N/A Routed up to Vcc
13 Ground Ground Routed to ground
14 KEY
15 IRTX IRTX Routed to IRTX pin on SIO
16 Vcc Vcc Vcc
```

http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Business-PCs-Deskpro-EVO/DX5150-F-P1-pin-id/td-p/927407

http://bizsupport.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00307105/c00307105.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I spent a long time tracking down the info on the headers for the MS-7050 motherboard. It's an OEM version exclusively used in the HP DX5150 desktop (SFF) and mini-tower PCs, so there is no information on it from the MSI website. To help others find this more easily, I've posted it online and also made it available as a PDF here:
http://homepage.ntlworld.com/loz-saunders/MS-7050/

Hope this helps someone.